# Finding a limit of a sequence if nth term is not given

Tags: calculus

I have that $x_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $x_n = \sqrt{ 2 \sqrt{x_{n-1} } } $. After working out details, I obtain that

$$ x_n = \sqrt{ 2 \cdot 2^{ 1/2^n} } = \sqrt{ 2^{ (2^n+1)/2^n} } = 2^{(2^n + 1)/2^{n+1}} \to \sqrt{2} $$

Is this the correct limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume convergence first, hence for $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n-1}=x$.

We get $x=(2(x)^{1/2})^{1/2}=2^{1/2}x^{1/4}$. Take the forth power to get the following.

$$x^4=4x$$

$$x^3=4$$

$$x=\sqrt[3]{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

No, but since you have not included how you worked out your details, I don't that I can accurately say what went wrong.

But, if $\log_2(x_n)=y_n$, then $$y_n=\log_2(x_n)=\log_2(\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt[4]{{x_{n-1}}})=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\log_2{x_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{y_{n-1}}{4}$$

Then if $$y_n-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{4}(y_{n-1}-\frac{2}{3})$$

So we have that $y_n$ converges to $\frac{2}{3}$. So $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ converges to $\sqrt[3]{4}$.